# getting mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a simple process that checks if a username is taken already during the login process.

I have a simple php script that querys the database and then i check to see if there are any results and echos a response to the user

the full error that i get is:
mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home1/tbronson/public_html/sandbox/uname_check.php on line 9

The entire php script is:

```
<?php 
$user = "(removed for security)";
$pass = "(removed for security)";
$db = "budgetbidders_users";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

$uname = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['uname'] ) );
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE uname =  '" .$uname . '");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result); //line 9

if ($numrows > 0) {
    $end_result = "Username already taken";
    }
else {
    $end_result = "";
    }
echo $end_result;   



?>
```

I have searched for hours and tried multiple variations, this seems to be the closest to correct that i can find, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few errors in your code.

The following line has a missing double-quote before the single quote for `$uname`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  `users` 
WHERE uname =  '" .$uname . '");
                           ^
```

However it would be better to use prepared statements or PDO along or you can use:

```
WHERE uname =  '$uname' // instead
```

Plus, you're mixing the deprecated `mysql_*` function with the `mysqli_*` functions.

`mysqli_query` and [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) where [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) needs to be changed to `mysqli_num_rows`

I also suggest you change:

```
$uname = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['uname'] ) );
```

to:

```
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);
```

And:

```
WHERE uname =  '" .$uname . "'
```

to:

```
WHERE uname =  '$uname'
```

You can make any modifications you wish, both will work. [**Do read this article on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) on how to prevent SQL injection.

Give this a try now:

```
<?php 
$user = "(removed for security)";
$pass = "(removed for security)";
$db = "budgetbidders_users";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

// the line below is better to use
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);

// this is your original line of code which will work also
// $uname = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['uname'] ) );
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE uname =  '" .$uname . "' ");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); //line 9

if ($numrows > 0) {
        $end_result = "Username already taken";
} else {
    $end_result = "";
}
echo $end_result;   

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, and I finely well read up on sql injection thank you fir the links

Comment: You're very much welcome, glad I could help. @user3138143 Stay safe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That is beacase u are using mysql_ instead of mysqli_

try this

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result):
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` syntax.

In your case you need:

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

And you have a syntax error on the line before it (a missing quote).